# What is the difference between 'YYYY' and 'RRRR' in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 queries in SQL:

```
select trunc(to_date('27-Jul-1987'),'YYYY') FROM dual;
```

and

```
select trunc(to_date('27-Jul-1987'),'RRRR') FROM dual;
```

Both are giving me the same result. What is the difference between 'RRRR' and 'YYYY'?

Comment: Even your code similar to what you have posted here (I say similar because SQL `select` is not allowed in a PL/SQL block, instead `select into` have to be used) might be located in a PL/SQL block your question is not PL/SQL related at all, but Oracle SQL issue.

Comment: Rtm . It's faster!

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`YYYY` gives the current year as 4 digits.

`RRRR` format means 2-digit years in the range `00` to `49` are assumed to be in the *current* century (ie have the same first two digits as the current year), and years given as `50` through `99` are assumed to be in the *previous* century.

Comment: Hmm, I am reporting from an Oracle table with a DATE column, and it gives me strange years whether I use rrrr or yyyy. 
select  IVDATE
,to_char(IVDATE,'yyyy-mm-dd') as YYYYdate
,to_char(IVDATE,'rrrr-mm-dd') as RRRRdate
from DODGYTABLE
where IVDATE < To_Date('20000101','RRRRMMDD')

I get [27-SEP-16 00:00:00] [1216-09-27] [1216-09-27] amongst other rows

Answer (score 13):

If the first 2 digits for the year are not specified in the date to be converted:

- YYYY will always return the current year.
- RRRR returns the year based on the current specified year in the database.

Try this sample code:

```
SELECT TO_DATE ('010199', 'MMDDYYYY') AS date_a,
       TO_DATE ('010199', 'MMDDYY') AS date_b,
       TO_DATE ('010199', 'MMDDRR') AS date_c,
       TO_DATE ('010199', 'MMDDRRRR') AS date_d
  FROM DUAL;
```

The results when run on 12/01/2014:

```
 DATE_A       DATE_B       DATE_C        DATE_D   
 ---------    ---------    ---------     ---------  
 1/1/0099      1/1/2099     1/1/1999      1/1/1999
```

This oracle [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00215) gives a great description and examples.

From the above [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00215):

> - If the specified two-digit year is 00 to 49, then
>
>   - If the last two digits of the current year are 00 to 49, then the       returned year has the same first two digits as the current year.
>   - If the last two digits of the current year are 50 to 99, then the    first 2 digits of the returned year are 1 greater than the first 2 digits of the current year.
> - If the specified two-digit year is 50 to 99, then
>
>   - If the last two digits of the current year are 00 to 49, then the    first 2 digits of the returned year are 1 less than the first 2  digits of the current year.
>   - If the last two digits of the current year are 50 to 99, then the    returned year has the same first two digits as the current year.

Answer (score 8):

This:

```
SQL> select  to_char(to_date('72-01-01','rrrr-mm-dd'),'yyyy') from dual;
```

will give you:

```
1972
```

But this:

```
SQL> select  to_char(to_date('72-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy') from dual;
```

will give you:

```
0072
```