# Inserting dates before year 1950 in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem getting correct date. When I copy dates from one table to another

```
insert into table1 select some_date from some_table
```

it inserts wrong date. The problem only occurs for dates with year before 1950. In table1 I have date 1.1.1949 and when I copy it to some_table I get date 2049-1-1

How do I get correct date...  1949-1-1?

Comment: why are you converting to char when copying dates?

Comment: Use `YYYY` instead of `RRRR`.

Comment: it used to be just some_date but then I thought it would make any difference. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use:

```
to_char(some_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

`RRRR` is for 2 digit years, assuming same century. Read here: [What is the difference between 'YYYY' and 'RRRR' in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812916/what-is-the-difference-between-yyyy-and-rrrr-in-pl-sql)

Comment: Might be worth linking to the [Date Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm) as well...

Comment: You are right. At first I didn't used to_char and probably because my NLS_DATE_FORMAT is set to DD.MM.RR it inserted the wrong year.