# DOB(date) is getting wrongly save in Oracle DB

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-web-api, oracle11g

I am working on a web API where I need to save date of birth. I came across a weird  behavior where when I saving a date 02-05-1929. But it is getting saved as 02-05-2029 in oracle db. I realized that it happening for all dates prior to 1950. Can anyone please help me understand why it is happening

Comment: Have a look at <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605864/inserting-dates-before-year-1950-in-oracle> That should help!

Comment: This the explanation in the link : If the specified two-digit year is 00 to 49, then
If the last two digits of the current year are 00 to 49, then the returned year has the same first two digits as the current year.
 As per this explanation, 1929 is correctly getting saved as 2029. But I need to save 1929 only. what to do?

Comment: @AshwiniKumar I think you will need to check through all of your code to make sure you are always working with a DateTime type, if not, then making sure the representation always has the full 4 digit year.

Comment: Are you saving "02-05-1929" or "02-05-29"? Also, what is the data type you're sending to Oracle, is it a string or a DateTime?

Comment: @Karlsen: I am saving "02-05-1929" and data type of the variable is DateTime

Answer (score 0):

As it's a web API I assume you get your dates as a string. You store it in a column of datatype `DATE`, presumably. You need to take control of the conversion from string into `DATE`, best by supplying the date format yourself:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE my_table(..., my_date, ...)
VALUES(..., TO_DATE(my_datestring,'DD-MM-YYYY'), ...)
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more, what was the error message, what is the create statement of your table etc..