# (oracle) returning 00 in data conversion

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running this SQL code.

```
select  to_char(to_date('14-05-13','yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy') from dual;
```

I don't know why oracle returns `0014` for me.

Could someone help me?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812916/what-is-the-difference-between-yyyy-and-rrrr-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace YYYY to RRRR

```
select to_char(to_date('14-05-13','rrrr-mm-dd'),'rrrr') from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are giving it "yyyy-mm-dd" for a date format, but you are giving it a date of "14-05-13".  So, you are literally telling it that the date is 5/13/0014.

Try either:

```
select to_char(to_date('14-05-13','yy-mm-dd'),'yyyy') from dual
```

or preferably:

```
select to_char(to_date('2014-05-13','yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy') from dual;
```