# Date range problems in Oracle. How do I correctly grab date ranges in this format?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-date-functions

I have this Oracle database, and it has a list of dates in this format: `mm/dd/yy 0:00:00 AM/PM` (1 for January, instead of 01; 1 for the day, instead of 01, and so forth).

When I try a query such as:

```
select DATELIST from CORE.DATE_TEST
where to_date(DATELIST) >= to_date('8/27/2015', 'mm/dd/yy') AND to_date(DATELIST, 'mm/dd/yy') <= to_date('9/27/2015', 'mm/dd/yy');
```

It gives me the following error: `ORA-01843: not a valid month`. I can't see how 27 is a valid month either, but it will accept that input if I try

When I try to change it to the expected date formats:

1. `m/dd/yy`
2. `mm/dd/yyyy`
3. `m/d/yy`

I get this error: `ORA-01821: date format not recognized`

When I switch it up to `dd/mm/yy`, it sort of works, but not really; it gives me invalid results.

However, this works:

```
select DATELIST from CORE.DATE_TEST
where to_date(DATELIST) >= to_date('8/27/2015', 'mm/dd/yy')
```

The PL/SQL script is breaking on the following addition:

```
AND to_date(DATELIST, 'mm/dd/yy') <= to_date('9/27/2015', 'mm/dd/yy');
```

When I replace the above code with this:

```
SELECT to_date(DATELIST, 'dd/mm/yy') 
    FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
WHERE DATELIST >= to_date('8/27/2015', 'mm/dd/yy')
    AND DATELIST <= to_date('9/27/2015', 'mm/dd/yy');
```

It works, and is a million times faster, but it won't correctly parse the date range. The lesser-than-or-equal-to (`<=`) operator is only grabbing data between `8/27/2015`, and `9/26/2015`. Isn't it supposed to get 8/27/2015 to 9/27/2015?

So I change the last line to this:

```
AND DATELIST <= to_date('9/27/2015', 'mm/dd/yy') + 1
```

...and it works, but it doesn't seem like I'm handling this right.

What am I doing wrong? Also, if there's a better, more efficient way of doing this, I'm all ears.

Comment: "The lesser-than-or-equal-to (<=) operator is only grabbing data between 8/27/2015, and 9/26/2015. Isn't it supposed to get 8/27/2015 to 9/27/2015?" You say your dates have times, as well. Bear in mind that any date after exactly midnight in the morning on 27 September is later than the date 27 September. If you want to include the whole of 27 September, you should be looking for dates < 28 September. Also, why on earth aren't you just storing your date as a `date`?

Comment: Question:  Why is DATELIST not one of the [Oracle DateTime types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm), such as `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: @Matt Gibson, that's a good question. Could you show me an example of how to do it? I'm relatively new to SQL, let alone PLSQL which I just picked up a few hours ago.

Comment: @Powerlord, the DATELIST is using `DATE`. I'm probably not handling this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of issues in your original question, I'll try to address some or all of them here:

> ```
> When I try a query such as:
> ```

```
select DATELIST from CORE.DATE_TEST
where to_date(DATELIST) >= to_date('8/27/2015', 'mm/dd/yy') AND to_date(DATELIST, 'mm/dd/yy') <= to_date('9/27/2015', 'mm/dd/yy');
```

> ```
> It gives me the following error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
> ```

You are not specifying a date format when you specify `to_date(DATELIST)` therefore it will default to the NLS setting for the default date format. You should always specify a date format whenever you use TO_DATE to prevent this from happening and ensure your date formats are explicit (and you are using `yy` and yet you are specifying a 4 digit year so you should use `yyyy`).

Try this instead (assuming `DATELIST` is a `DATE` datatype):

```
select TO_CHAR(DATELIST, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') -- Use whatever date format is clearest to you
  from CORE.DATE_TEST
 where DATELIST >= to_date('8/27/2015 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND DATELIST <= to_date('9/27/2015 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

If `DATELIST` is a `VARCHAR2` then you'll need to see what date format the values are stored in within the column and format the query accordingly.

> The lesser-than-or-equal-to (<=) operator is only grabbing data
>   between 8/27/2015, and 9/26/2015. Isn't it supposed to get 8/27/2015
>   to 9/27/2015?

When you use `TO_DATE` and don't specify a time portion of the date, it defaults to 00:00:00 for the hours, minutes and seconds. If you want the full date range try to be more explicit:

```
SELECT to_date(DATELIST, 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss') 
    FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
WHERE DATELIST >= to_date('8/27/2015 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    AND DATELIST <= to_date('9/27/2015 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

The reason the query is much faster is, I suspect, that you have an index on the `DATELIST` column which you are defeating when you wrap it with a `TO_DATE` call such as `TO_DATE(DATELIST, 'mm/dd/yyyy')`.

If the datatype of `DATELIST` is `DATE` then leave it as such, if it's `VARCHAR2` then you have some additional date formatting issues.

Hope it helps

EDIT:

I think your issue is to do with the hidden time portions of the `DATE` datatype DATELIST.

If you have the value:
09/27/2015 10:35:12

Even if you don't care about the 10:35:12 portion of that date, it is still there. If you then try to use the following where clause:

```
WHERE DATELIST >= TO_DATE('09/26/2015', 'MM/DD/RRRR')
  AND DATELIST <= TO_DATE('09/27/2015', 'MM/DD/RRRR');
```

Then the value won't be picked up as it is greater than:
09/27/2015 00:00:00.

You need to either up the higher bound by a day or specify the time portion e.g.:

```
WHERE DATELIST >= TO_DATE('09/26/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
  AND DATELIST <= TO_DATE('09/27/2015 23:59:59', 'MM/DD/RRRR HH24:MI:SS');
```

EDIT2:
Working with the OP, he has said that this has worked:

```
SELECT to_date(DATELIST, 'dd/mm/yy') as Date_Accessed 
  FROM CORE.DATE_TEST 
 WHERE (trunc(DATELIST) >= to_date('9/27/2015', 'mm/dd/yy')) 
   AND (trunc(DATELIST) <= to_date('9/30/2015', 'mm/dd/yy'));
```

Though this will defeat any index on the DATELIST column.

Comment: Yeah, I tried `yyyy`, and it converted the date to 2027, which is completely incorrect.

Comment: OK, then try `RRRR` instead of `YYYY` see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812916/what-is-the-difference-between-yyyy-and-rrrr-in-oracle-sql

Comment: Your last example works, but only up to 9/26/2015. Using `<=` doesn't work.

Comment: I replaced the time with `trunc()` and I'm still having the same issue here. It only goes up to 9/26.

Comment: Is the `DATELIST` column a `DATE` datatype? If so you could just use: `DATELIST < TO_DATE('09/28/2015', 'MM/DD/RRRR')`

Comment: Also, what do you mean "It only goes up to 9/26/2015"? What further do you want? Higher months or dates from 09/27/2015?

Comment: I can't use chat, it's blocked here :-(

Comment: Yep, it is. Still doesn't work. I tried this, and it works (very fast, too), but I feel like I'm doing something horribly wrong for it to work: `SELECT to_date(DATELIST, 'dd/mm/yy') as Date_Accessed
    FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
WHERE (DATELIST >= trunc(to_date('9/27/2015', 'mm/dd/yy')))
    AND (DATELIST <= trunc(to_date('9/30/2015', 'mm/dd/yy') + 1));`

Comment: I want everything between a set date range. The answers you gave me only go `from (date_from) to (date_to -1)`. It's always missing a day. The `<=` operator isn't working right.

Comment: You're trunc'ing the wrong side of the statement. It does nothing to the dates you're specifying as you haven't added any time portion to them in the first place. Try this: `SELECT to_char(DATELIST, 'dd/mm/rrrr hh24:mi:ss') as Date_Accessed FROM CORE.DATE_TEST WHERE DATELIST >= to_date('09/27/2015', 'mm/dd/rrrr') AND DATELIST < to_date('10/01/2015', 'mm/dd/rrrr');` This should give you all dates from the 27th Sept to one second before midnight on the 30th Sept.

Comment: Didn't work, and you had your formats mixed up, lol... but you put me on the right path: truncing the wrong side of the statement. I did that, and it's now working perfectly. Can you update your answer with that? Because I'll check it since it works. `SELECT to_date(DATELIST, 'dd/mm/yy') as Date_Accessed
    FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
WHERE (trunc(DATELIST) >= to_date('9/27/2015', 'mm/dd/yy'))
    AND (trunc(DATELIST) <= to_date('9/30/2015', 'mm/dd/yy'));`

Comment: I'll update it, glad I could help. Please see my most recent edit though as it might give you some further info into your issue. Using TRUNC on the DATELIST column will mean your query is slower as I suspect it'll now not use any index on that column.

Comment: All done. Thanks for your help. Regarding the index, that's ok., I guess; I only need weekly data, and it's instanteous. This stuff only needs to be accessed once per week. **EDIT**: Actually, your recent edit is perfect. I'll be using that instead since it's absurdly quick. Thanks a ton, man!

Comment: Good answer, though: `...AND DATELIST <= to_date('9/27/2015 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');` bear in mind that Oracle timestamp columns (and other database's DATETIME, etc. columns) can be stored with more precision than a single second, so there might still be times on that day that are later than that, e.g. at a half-second to midnight. I'm sure it'll be fine with the DATE we seem to be using here, but best practice with most database systems would be to look for dates earlier than the following day using `<` rather than `<=`.

Comment: @MattGibson, I agree, I was trying to illustrate the point about the time portions of dates to the OP and figured that if I got into millis etc. it would cloud the issue. Good point though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using to_date use the ANSI date literal:

```
DATE '2015-09-27'
```

From oracle documentation:

> The ANSI date literal contains no time portion, and must be specified
>   in exactly this format ('YYYY-MM-DD').

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that did not work. That was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: Ok. I can't access an oracle server right now. It worked in postres. But at least it would make for a lighter syntax. And there is no ambiguity when interpreting the date format.