# Using 4-digit year in Oracle for centuries < 1900

Tags: database, oracle, date

I'm needing to use 4 digit years in dates for a database centered around historical facts (e.g. Beethoven's birth (1700s)/death (1800s) dates).  I can't seem to figure out how to input this information with the INSERT statement.  Here's what I've got so far, but obviously it doesn't work...

```
CREATE TABLE musicians (
id NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
first_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
pri_inst VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
born DATE NOT NULL,
died DATE
);

INSERT INTO musicians (
inc_mus_id.nextval, 'Ludwig', 'van Beethoven', 'Piano', '16-Dec-1770', '26-Mar-1827')
```

Thoughts?

EDIT: Here's the actual error message: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification.

EDIT 2: Also tried this: 
    INSERT INTO musicians (
    inc_mus_id.nextval, 'Ludwig', 'van Beethoven', 'Piano', TO_DATE('16-Dec-1770', 'dd-Mon-RRRR'), TO_DATE('26-Mar-1827', 'dd-Mon-RRRR'))

EDIT 3: Solved!  Thanks @Rene!  Also, could do it without the TO_DATE function with dates formatted like: '16/Dec/1770'.

Comment: It's good practice to always use to_date and specify the format.  Otherwise you leave it to environment settings and they might not always be the same. As suggested by Lalit, use YYYY instead of RRRR.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812916/what-is-the-difference-between-yyyy-and-rrrr-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem does not seem to be date related but an error in your syntax.
Try this:

```
insert into musicians
   (id
   ,first_name
   ,last_name
   ,pri_inst
   ,born
   ,died)
values
   (inc_mus_id.nextval
   ,'Ludwig'
   ,'van Beethoven'
   ,'Piano'
   ,to_date('16-Dec-1770', 'dd-Mon-RRRR')
   ,to_date('26-Mar-1827', 'dd-Mon-RRRR'));
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks!  I thought you didn't have to call the columns if you were using all of them in the correct order.  Haven't been required to do that in other exercises.  Any idea why this setup would require it?  Calling the sequence, maybe?

Comment: Maybe you were missing the values keyword.

Comment: Ugh...totally right.  That's why I'm not in charge of IBM's entire database yet.  :P  Thanks for the help @Rene!

Comment: @Rene Why `RRRR`? `YYYY` should be just fine. `RR` has a different meaning especially meant for Y2K bug.

Comment: Ah! That came from OP's edits in the question, not the original one where the code is formatted and easy to interpret. By the way, you could consider ANSI Date literal when there is no time portion involved, and it is also NLS independent since it uses a fixed format.

Comment: @TheDoc Whilst you don't **have** to list all the columns you're inserting into if you're inserting into all the columns in the table, it's good practice to do so. Especially if this is production code. Consider what would happen if someone added a new column and your code wasn't changed: it would fail.

Comment: You should also specify the NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE if you work with months names.

Answer (score 3):

The `ORA-01747` error is because you have forgotten the `VALUES` keyword before the brackets.

A more robust way of inserting the dates is to either use an [ANSI Date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ):

```
INSERT INTO musicians VALUES (
  inc_mus_id.nextval,
  'Ludwig',
  'van Beethoven',
  'Piano',
  DATE '1770-12-16',
  DATE '1827-03-26'
)
```

or use `TO_DATE`

```
INSERT INTO musicians VALUES (
  inc_mus_id.nextval,
  'Ludwig',
  'van Beethoven',
  'Piano',
  TO_DATE( '16-Dec-1770', 'DD-Mon-YYYY' ),
  TO_DATE( '26-Mar-1827', 'DD-Mon-YYYY' )
)
```

Comment: INSERT INTO musicians (
inc_mus_id.nextval, 'Ludwig', 'van Beethoven', 'Piano', DATE '1770-12-16', DATE '26-Mar-1827') gives me the same error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification.  Did I miss something in the sequence definition, maybe?

Comment: Updated. The date being entered as a string only works as the format you're using matches the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` - if you do `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';` then try to run your insert using string values of a different format it will fail with `ORA-01858`.

Comment: @MT0 No need of altering the session as the actual useful thing with ANSI Date literal is that it is **NLS independent**.  OP is missing the `VALUES` keyword. Also, the issue is with `DATE '26-Mar-1827'` which is wrong. ANSI Date literal uses a fixed format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`. By the way, +1 for suggesting **ANSI Date literal**, I was about to post an answer, but since you have already mentioned, I upvoted it.

Comment: @LalitKumarB My point was `INSERT INTO table_name ( date_column ) VALUES ( '01-JAN-1900' )` will work (and perform an implicit `TO_DATE`) **only** when `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD-MON-YYYY`; however, if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is some other format then it will throw `ORA-01858`. So, in the case where the date format does not match the NLS settings then you must either use an ANSI literal (which, as you said, is NLS independant) or use `TO_DATE` and specify the format. (And if the OP does use an implicit conversion don't be surprised when everything breaks when it is ported to a different machine.)

Comment: @MTO hmm... I saw your reply to OP's comment with `ORA-01858` about `ORA-01747` which is due to missing `VALUES` keyword. And, he commented that he is using ANSI Date literal. So, it seemed to me like you suggested alter session for that. **Perhaps the comments were edited, and now seems different**. Anyway, everything seems fine :-)