# Getting required quarter dates - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to get the required output (column 2) based on the input (column 1) in a single sql statement.

```
-201701 - 31-Dec-2016
-201702 - 31-Dec-2016
-201703 - 31-Mar-2017
-201704 - 31-Mar-2017
-201705 - 31-Mar-2017
-201706 - 30-Jun-2017
-201707 - 30-Jun-2017
-201708 - 30-Jun-2017
-201709 - 30-Sep-2017
-201710 - 30-Sep-2017
-201711 - 30-Sep-2017
-201712 - 31-Dec-2017
```

Till now i got a solution which works fine:

```
select TRUNC(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE([Column 1] value,'RRRRMM'))+1,'Q')-1 from dual
```

Please advise if there are any other solutions OR if there is any issue which I will face with mine when moving forward in years ahead...

Comment: Your formula looks correct and is unlikely to have problems in the future. One nitpick, why use RRRR instead of YYYY? It won't break anything here, but YYYY should be preferred unless there is a very good reason to use RRRR.

Comment: @mathguy Force of habit. I have been using oracle for a while and I always use RRRR. Anyway I just tried to find a difference between two: check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812916/what-is-the-difference-between-yyyy-and-rrrr-in-oracle-sql). It plays a role when you specify only 2 digits of the year but has no significance when you specify 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will handle the future.

There could be simple modification using this expression:

```
 trunc(trunc(add_months(dt,+1),'mm'),'q')-1
```

e.g.:

```
with dat as (
  select trunc(to_date('2017'||to_char(level,'00'),'yyyymm')) dt 
    from dual where level <= 12 
    connect by level < 12)
select dt, trunc(trunc(add_months(dt,+1),'mm'),'q')-1 quarter 
  from dat;
```

But so far it woudn't make much difference.

Consider using YYYY insted of RRRR. The RRRR mask assumes current century for calculations.

Comment: the `RRRR` format mask doesn't assume current century if the year you're passing in has 4 digits (ie. `to_date('2129', 'rrrr')` outputs a date that has 2129 as the year). It's only important when working with two-digit years, and was a workaround for the Y2K bug. In this day and age, no one should be using two digit years... ha. ha. ha! </ironic laugh>

Comment: Thank You got the point. Do not ever rely on expression simplicity. Could bring a bit of trouble. I didn't know what was it designed originally to. Thanks. I hope IT stuff won't run to any kind if trouble in 2099 (again). ;)

Comment: I think the next issue is [the unix year 2038 problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). Then most likely, Y10K, but I don't plan on hanging around that long! 

Comment: Your query works as well.  As you pointed out it won't make much of a difference so i will continue using the old 1. Thanks for replying :)

Answer (score -1):

```
with dat as (
  select trunc(to_date('2017'||to_char(level,'00'),'yyyymm')) dt 
    from dual where level <= 12 
    connect by level < 12)
select dt, trunc( dt + 32, 'q')-1 quarter 
  from dat;
```

Comment: _why_ do you believe this is the answer? _how_ does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong.

Comment: ???? There's a context! The OP describes his problem, gives his solution (also without any explanation, just as I did). He didn't do anything wrong, and I didn't tell him to change anything. He asks for others solutions, and I gave him one. And I didn't thought that it needed any explanation. I just assumed that any person would understand that 32 days after the first day of a month you are always in the next month. Just as simple as the query of the OP, one day after the last day of a month you are in the next month. But be assured, I will never answer a question her on SO, without a context

Comment: You should add that explanation to your post. There is no context without the question, and that is the problem. This is a site for learning. Posts that are _only_ code are generally not well welcomed. Your answer should provide a context link to the question, and explain why it works the way it does. You should not "assume" what other users will already know, that is not what this site is for. It's a learning site, your answer should reflect a _full answer_, and an explanation so that _other people_ can learn from it in the future.

Comment: You should refer to the other answer posted above that has nearly identical code as yours but also has more information about it.