# Oracle SQL: Wrong Year Output when using to_date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a Oracle SQL Statement for a report.
User is able to put in FROM / TO Dates and I compare it to the issued rows with (simplyfied):

```sql
… where changedate < to_date(user_input, 'dd.MM.YYYY')…
```

Field "changedate" is Datatype DATE in this Table.

Code:

```sql
select to_date(changedate, 'dd.MM.YYYY') from TICKETSTATUS;
```

The field usually contains

```sql
30.03.2019 21:50:48
```

but my Output with converting it with the Code is:

```sql
30.03.0019
```

Why does it do this? I want '2019' as the year but it seems to erase the first 2 numbers?
Can somebody explain and help me fix that issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this answer and try out options - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812916/what-is-the-difference-between-yyyy-and-rrrr-in-oracle-sql

Comment: Why are you storing DATE values in a VARCHAR column? That is a really bad idea to begin with.

Comment: The problem here is that you are calling `to_date` on a column which is *already* a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to insert by two types of formatting `rrrr` and `yyyy` for the year value to see the difference :

```
create table ticketstatus( id int, changedate date );
insert into ticketstatus values(1,to_date('30.03.19','dd.mm.yyyy'));
insert into ticketstatus values(2,to_date('31.03.19','dd.mm.rrrr'));

select changedate
  from ticketstatus;

CHANGEDATE
------------ 
30.03.0019   
31.03.2019
```

Indeed, you can observe this versatile situation as below :

```
with ticketstatus(changedate) as
(
 select '30.03.19' from dual
)
select to_date(changedate,'dd.mm.yyyy') date_with_yy,
       to_date(changedate,'dd.mm.rrrr') date_with_rr
  from ticketstatus;

DATE_WITH_YY    DATE_WITH_RR
------------    ------------
30.03.0019      30.03.2019
```

This is known as `Year 2k problem`, and the year format `rrrr` stems from this problem. Therefore, the date format with `rrrr` may be used against such issues.

Comment: The actual issue is the `to_date` on something that is already in date format. Don't do that, ever. Using `rrrr` in this case just masks the issue. Remove the `to_date` instead - or, if you're wanting to remove the time part, use `trunc()` on the date.

Comment: You should **NEVER** use `TO_DATE` on a `DATE` column as this will involve an implicit conversion which is effectively `TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( changedate, (SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE  PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' ) ), 'dd.mm.rrrr' )` and if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `mm.dd.yyyy` (month and day swapped in US format) then unexpected things can occur.

Comment: yes thank you @Boneist. Now, I inserted the by applying `to_date` for string values such as `'30.03.19'` and `'31.03.19'`.

Comment: The data you are using is wrong as the OP stated that `changedate` has the `DATE` data type and you have changed it to a string data type. If you change the input to a date literal `DATE '2019-03-30'` and use `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'mm.dd.rrrr';` then you will see one of the issues we are talking about with this answer and why it is wrong to use `TO_DATE` on a date. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e02207ff717b958d0bfadfbcd2063730)

Comment: @MT0 as clearly you should see I'm converting string values to date values during the insertion such as `to_date('31.03.19','dd.mm.rrrr')`.

Comment: Not in the bottom query - you are using the `WITH` clause to generate a CTE with a string data type column.

Comment: @MT0 it's still of type string for the both cases (bottom or above), don't care about the name ( changedate ). `'30.03.19'` is a string.

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d7d450622392c0b5ce7f718112f56ffa) - This is how your query fails. Take the top DDL/DML statements (as per the data in the OP's question) and the bottom query (without the `WITH` clause) and apply them together with setting the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

Comment: @MT0 "This is how your query fails". No, consider : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e70ba698d1fccf56c6d926c1ac233f52 Those are what I did in the answer.

Comment: "Those are what I did in the answer". You may have done that (i.e. used a string input to `TO_DATE`) but that is not what the OP has stated is their data type in the question. If you use the OP's `DATE` data type then your query can fail when the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter changes (which any user can do in their own session without making any changes to your code).

Comment: @MT0 well, turned my head to the above and saw `to_date(changedate, 'dd.MM.YYYY')` and refreshed my mind about what OP wants and where the discussion stems from. So, you're right about this. +1

Answer (score 2):

**[TL;DR]**

1. Do not use `TO_DATE` on a `DATE` data type.
2. Your problem may be on data entry rather than on output as you are probably getting 2-digit year inputs when a 4-digit year is expected.

---

You do not need to convert `change_date` to a `DATE` using `TO_DATE` as it is already a `DATE` data type. Just use:

```
select changedate
from   TICKETSTATUS;
```

If you want your date values to have a specific format then use `TO_CHAR` (not `TO_DATE`):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( changedate, 'dd.mm.yyyy' )
FROM   TICKETSTATUS;
```

> but my Output [] is:
>
> ```
> 30.03.0019
> ```

That may be because you have an error elsewhere in your code that is probably inserting dates from a string with a 2-digit year where a 4-digit year is expected:

```
CREATE TABLE TicketStatus ( changedate DATE );

INSERT INTO TicketStatus ( changedate ) VALUES ( TO_DATE( '30.03.19', 'dd.mm.yyyy' ) );
```

Then the year will be `0019`.

However, if you use the `RR` format model for years (or, depending on appropriateness, the `YY` format model):

```
INSERT INTO TicketStatus ( changedate ) VALUES ( TO_DATE( '30.03.19', 'dd.mm.rr' ) );
```

Then the year will be `2019`.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( changedate, 'dd.mm.yyyy' )
FROM   TicketStatus
```

Outputs:

```
| TO_CHAR(CHANGEDATE,'DD.MM.YYYY') |
| :------------------------------- |
| 30.03.0019                       |
| 30.03.2019                       |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aaf5cda1c9edf687092d8a2f26c7031a)*

It could also be because the `NLS_DATE_SETTING` in your session is set to `dd.mm.yy` and the implicit conversion made using `TO_DATE` on a date column is removing the century but then **ALL** your dates would have the century `00` (rather than just some of the dates).