# Oracle Apex 19 - Date Picker - The application item stores the wrong 20th century, selecting a 19th date from the calendar

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

On my page I have an application item where the user has to select the date of birth from a date picker calendar. Since the user must be of age (according to Italian law) and I do not allow entry for people over 90, I have set the minimum and maximum to -100 and -18. When selecting the year, if the user selects a 19th century date from the date picker, the system mistakenly stores the corresponding 20th century year. How can I solve? I would like to avoid dividing the date into 3 distinct elements(day+month+year).

Comment: I would imagine that somewhere in your stack you are handling the date as a string with a 2-digit year, and when that string is converted to an actual date the century is being assumed. Make sure you are using 4-digit years; or preferably don't convert it to/from a string at all, if that can be avoided.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I solved the issue exactly as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with explicit setting the format mask DD-MON-YYYY on the date picker application item. The YYYY format uses the selected century correctly. I guess that by default the date picker format considered is DD-MON-RRRR.

This helps
"What is the difference between 'YYYY' and 'RRRR' in Oracle SQL"
[What is the difference between 'YYYY' and 'RRRR' in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812916/what-is-the-difference-between-yyyy-and-rrrr-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: I suggest entering a minimum date that forces the user to change the proposed default year. In the absence of this first click, if you select the day without changing the year, the problem recurs.